# API support for manual approval of promoted builds in Jenkins?

Tags: api, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there any way to programmatically approve the Jenkins promoted build?
In job configuration it has been set to "Only when manually approved".

Answer (score 4):

Yes! Although I haven't found any documentation for it and so it might not be a stable solution. I found this using the browser developer tools. Make sure  "Only when manually approved" is checked.

Here's an example:

```
curl 'https://jenkins/job/z-promotion-test/3/promotion/promotionProcess/promotion_test/promotionCondition/hudson.plugins.promoted_builds.conditions.ManualCondition/approve' --data 'json=%7B%7D&Submit=Approve'
```

Authenticated version

```
curl 'http://<user>:<token>@jenkins/job/z-promotion-test/3/promotion/promotionProcess/promotion_test/promotionCondition/hudson.plugins.promoted_builds.conditions.ManualCondition/approve' --data 'json=%7B%7D&Submit=Approve'
```

See

1. http://jenkins/me/configure
2. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API

Answer (score 0):

I too got into the same situation. There is no documentation/help found nowhere. But after some serious plug n play below command made it work. Hope it helps. Please refer below URL
[API (curl)Command to Approve a promoted build Job in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39920650/api-curlcommand-to-approve-a-promoted-build-job-in-jenkins/39937330#39937330)

I know it is almost 2 years since the post published, but thought it could help some others with the same issue. Thanks